# Xamarin Forms for iOS 'Could not AOT the assembly'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, aot

i am develop an app using xamarin forms, when i deploy for android it works fine but for iOS it gives an error

Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/MyUser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/DemoApp.iOS/1200d99a740029217aed9915fa08d90d/C:/Users/MANISH~1.TIW/AppData/Local/Temp/vs370F.tmp/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone6.1-12.0/mtouch-cache/3-Build/DemoApp.iOS.exe'   DemoApp.iOS

So can anyone please help me out from this issue ?

Build Log:

```
2>E:\BudhiPrakash Data\android-sdk-new\tools\XamarinProjects\MyApps\ExampleApp\ExampleApp.iOS\Controls\CustomElementFrameRenderer.cs(35,35,35,75): warning CS0618: 'Frame.OutlineColorProperty' is obsolete: 'OutlineColorProperty is obsolete as of version 3.0.0. Please use BorderColorProperty instead.'
2>E:\BudhiPrakash Data\android-sdk-new\tools\XamarinProjects\MyApps\ExampleApp\ExampleApp.iOS\Service\IosDownloader.cs(34,30,34,32): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
2>E:\BudhiPrakash Data\android-sdk-new\tools\XamarinProjects\MyApps\ExampleApp\ExampleApp.iOS\Controls\CustomElementFrameRenderer.cs(67,33,67,64): warning CS0618: 'Frame.OutlineColor' is obsolete: 'OutlineColor is obsolete as of version 3.0.0. Please use BorderColor instead.'
2>  ExampleApp.iOS -> E:\BudhiPrakash Data\android-sdk-new\tools\XamarinProjects\MyApps\ExampleApp\ExampleApp.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\ExampleApp.iOS.exe
2>  Detected signing identity:
2>    Code Signing Key: "iPhone Developer: AVC SDF (234)" (3434)
2>    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" (23423-423423-4234-234-234)
2>    Bundle Id: com.app
2>    App Id: SDFSDFSD.com.app
2>  /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/rajeev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ExampleApp.iOS/1200d99a740029217aed9915fa08d90d/C:/Users/MANISH~1.TIW/AppData/Local/Temp/vs370F.tmp/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone6.1-12.0/response-file.rsp -v -v -v -v 
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning : The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/rajeev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ExampleApp.iOS/1200d99a740029217aed9915fa08d90d/C:/Users/MANISH~1.TIW/AppData/Local/Temp/vs370F.tmp/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone6.1-12.0/mtouch-cache/3-Build/ExampleApp.iOS.exe'
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Diagnose Log:

```
CopyingFile - Path: /Users/rajeev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/HelpBuddiePrism.iOS/1200d99a740029217aed9915fa08d90d/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone6.1-12.0/HelpBuddiePrism.iOS.app/Close.png
 CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
 CreatingStagingDirectory - PercentComplete: 5%
 ExtractingPackage - PercentComplete: 15%
 InspectingPackage - PercentComplete: 20%
 TakingInstallLock - PercentComplete: 20%
 PreflightingApplication - PercentComplete: 30%
 VerifyingApplication - PercentComplete: 40%
 APIInternalError: Failed to unhide archs in executable file:///private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.MG8Wit/extracted/HelpBuddiePrism.iOS.app/HelpBuddiePrism.iOS
```

Comment: Are you using the latest Visual-Studio? The MT3001 error can have many causes, you can follow this [comment-](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4012#issuecomment-528482883) to get more help.

Comment: i am using Visual studio 2019 updated v16.3.2 this comment has no solution.

Comment: I mean you can fire a issue with build log,sometimes it is hard for us to give you a solution directly with just an error message. You can put your build log here too.

Comment: I added build and diagnose log, can you please check?

Comment: Do you see the same error in the Diagnostic log when deploying to a iOS simulator and a real iOS device? Have you updated your Visual studio to the latest version?

Comment: it didn't work, same issue

Comment: Are you using some third-part libraries? I found a [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/155755/visual-studio-2019-and-ios-native-linking-failed) which has the same problem with you, you can have a look at it.